# Executing command ps with a specific output via execlp

Tags: linux, shell

I can only display the column PPID, the executable name and the CPU usage. I have to execute the command ps via execlp, but I can't find the correct syntax for it to work. Any suggestions?

I tried `execlp("ps","ps", "-o","ppid cmd cpu", (char *) NULL);`

And similar things, but it's still not working

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by `it's still not working`?

Comment: Maybe you could avoid running a `ps` and directly access `/proc/` - see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: Well it was an exercise and I had to run ps as many times as arguments entered via command. Leeduhem's answer has been the solution, it was just a matter of syntax (commas between ppid, cmd and cpu were missing and that was the source of the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
execlp("ps","ps", "-o","ppid,cmd,cpu", (char *) NULL);
```